# No logro autenticar el usuario con JWT en Angular

Tags: angular, jwt, autenticacion

Hola estoy desarrollando un login en angular 13 pero no logro que el usuario se autentique usando el JWT que traigo desde el back. Cuando clickeo el botón de loguear, ejecuta una parte de la lógica pero no se loguea. La ruta por defecto es '/portfolio' y al loguearse debería de redirigir a la ruta '/admin'. Toda la parte de enviar las credenciales desde el front, comprobar si existe el usuario y devolver el token funcionan, pero la falla esta en la captura y procesamiento del token una ves que es devuelto por el back. No logro ver donde esta el error.

Este es el formulario HTML del loguin

```
<div class="login">
  <form
    class="custom-form"
    method=""
    (ngSubmit)="login($event)"
    [formGroup]="loginForm"
  >
    <h1>Login</h1> 
    
    <input
      type="email"
      formControlName="email"
      placeholder="Email"
      required="required"
    />
    <input
      type="password"
      formControlName="password"
      placeholder="password"
      required="required"
    />
    <p>Usuario: admin - Contraseña: admin</p>
    <button type="submit">Login</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Esta es la lógica del formulario

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
//import { UsersService } from 'src/app/servicios/users.service';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Users } from '../../users';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AutenticacionService } from 'src/app/servicios/autenticacion.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css'],
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit { 
  public loginForm!: FormGroup;
  constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,  
    private http: HttpClient,
    private ruta: Router,
    private autenticacionService:AutenticacionService
  ) {
  
    this.loginForm=this.formBuilder.group({
      email: [''],
      password: [''],
      deviceInfo:this.formBuilder.group({ 
       deviceId: ["17867868768"],
       devideType: ["DEVICE_TYPE_ANDROID"],
       notificationToken:["67657575eececc34"] 
      })       
         }) 

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }


get Email() {
  return this.loginForm.get('email');
}

get Password() {
  return this.loginForm.get('password');
}

login(event: Event) { 
  event.preventDefault;
  this.autenticacionService.iniciarSesion(this.loginForm.value).subscribe(data =>{
    console.log("DATA: " + JSON.stringify(data));
    this.ruta.navigate(['/admin']);       
  })
} 

}
```

Este es el servicio desde donde realizo la autenticación:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AutenticacionService {
url="http://localhost:8080/portfolio/users";
currentUserSubject: BehaviorSubject<any>;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { 
console.log("El servicio de autenticacion esta corriendo");
this.currentUserSubject = new BehaviorSubject<any>(JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('currentUser')|| '{}'));
 
}

  iniciarSesion(credenciales:any):Observable<any> {  
  return this.http.post(this.url, credenciales).pipe(map(data =>{
    sessionStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(data));
    this.currentUserSubject.next(data);      
    return data;   
  }))
 
}

get UsuarioAutenticado() { 
  return this.currentUserSubject.value; 
} 
}
```

Tengo las rutas protegidas con can active y guard. En la consola me devuelve FALSE cuando compara currentUser && currentUser.accessToken:
Este es mi guard:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot, CanActivate, Router, RouterStateSnapshot, UrlTree } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { AutenticacionService } from './autenticacion.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class GuardGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private autenticacionServicio:AutenticacionService, private route:Router) {
  }
  canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {
    let currentUser= this.autenticacionServicio.UsuarioAutenticado;
    if (currentUser && currentUser.accessToken) {     
      console.log("TRUE")
      return true;
    } else {
      console.log("FALSE") 
      this.route.navigate(['/portfolio']);
      return false;
    }
    
  }
  
}
```

Este es mi interceptor:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest} from "@angular/common/http";
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import { AutenticacionService } from './autenticacion.service';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class InterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(private autenticacionServicio:AutenticacionService) { }

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {    
   var currentUser= this.autenticacionServicio.UsuarioAutenticado;
   if (currentUser && currentUser.accessToken){    
    req=req.clone({
      setHeaders:{
        Authorization: `Bearer ${currentUser.accessToken}`
      }
    });
   }
   console.log("El interceptor esta corriendo" + JSON.stringify(currentUser));
    return next.handle(req);
  }

}
```

Este es el providers de mi app.module.ts:

```
 providers: [AdminComponent,
   {provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: InterceptorService, multi: true},
   ],
```

Y este es el app.routing:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'portfolio', component: PortfolioComponent },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'portfolio', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'admin', component: AdminComponent, canActivate:[GuardGuard]},
];
```

Esta es la clase controller que maneja el login:

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin (origins = "http://localhost:4200")
public class AuthController {
    @Autowired
    private IUsersService usuarioDao;  // private UsuarioDao usuarioDao
    @Autowired
    private JWTUtil jwtUtil;
    @RequestMapping(value = "portfolio/users", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String login(@RequestBody Users usuario) {
        Users usuarioLogueado = usuarioDao.obtenerUsuarioPorCredenciales (usuario);
        if (usuarioLogueado != null) {
            String tokenJwt = jwtUtil.create(String.valueOf(usuarioLogueado.getId()), usuarioLogueado.getEmail());
            return tokenJwt;
        }
        return "FAIL";
    }
}
```

Este es el servicio para obtener usuario por credenciales:

```
@Transactional  
  @Override
    public Users obtenerUsuarioPorCredenciales(Users usuario) {
       String query = "FROM Users WHERE email = :email" ;      
       //String query = "Select email from Users";
       List<Users> lista = entityManager.createQuery(query)
                .setParameter("email", usuario.getEmail())
                .getResultList();

        if (lista.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }
        String passwordHashed = lista.get(0).getPassword();
        Argon2 argon2 = Argon2Factory.create(Argon2Factory.Argon2Types.ARGON2id);
        if (argon2.verify(passwordHashed, usuario.getPassword())) {
            return lista.get(0);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Este es el registro de llamados del JWT: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el Session Storage:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Logre resolver parte del problema agregando { responseType: 'text' } al servicio de autenticación de esta manera:

```
  iniciarSesion(credenciales:any):Observable<any> {  
  return this.http.post(this.url, credenciales, { responseType: 'text' }).pipe(map(data =>{
    sessionStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(data));   
    this.currentUserSubject.next(data);      
    return data;   
  }))
 
}
```

Y la otra parte del problema de la siguiente manera:
Logre resolverlo remplazando `if (currentUser && currentUser.accessToken)` por `if (currentUser)` No se si es correcto pero funciona. Note que el método `get usuarioAutenticado() { return this.currentUserSubject.value; }` No devuelve el par clave-valor sino solo el valor y en mi condicional intento compararlos lo que me devuelve el error.

Comment: Haz un console.log a las diferentes variables de tu `canActivate` para comprobar que valores estas recibiendo. Creo que esta linea `return this.currentUserSubject.value; ` te esta traicionando.

Comment: Si hago un console.log a  esta linea :  `return this.currentUserSubject.value;` me devuelve el valor del token. Pero si tomo esta linea:  `else {console.log("FALSE")}  `y la remplazo por esta otra:  `console.log("EL TOKEN DEL USUARIO ES " + currentUser.accessToken) ` devuelve undefined ahora si lo pongo de esta otra manera:   `console.log("EL TOKEN DEL USUARIO ES " + currentUser) ` me devuelve el token. Cual podrá ser la causa?

Comment: Eso pasa porque  `this.currentUserSubject.value;` toma el último valor que se generó, y al parecer, en tu código, el token es un string y no contiene la llave `accessToken`.

Comment: Intenta hacer un `JSON.parse` dentro del next. (Si es que la data que recibes tiene estructura de json). Tambien puedes actualizar la pregunta con la estructura que estas mandando a `iniciarSesion`

Comment: Estoy recibiendo los datos del token como un string por eso me toco agregar la linea : `{ responseType: 'text' }`. Igual intente agregar el JSON.parse por si acaso pero me devolvía un error. Ya actualice la pregunta con la data que me pediste.

Comment: Necesito tambien ver el string que recibes, si es un jwt debes decodificarlo para obtener los valores.

Comment: Ya edite la pregunta con la información que me pedís. No se si te referías a eso específicamente, espero que sirva.

Comment: Si, esa es la info correcta. Recibes en token de manera correcta, pero en ningún lugar lo decodificas. Es necesario decoficarlo para obtener los datos. Para ver la estructura decodificada puedes meterte a https://jwt.io/. Pega tu token para que lo veas.

Comment: en el servicio implementa al método asi :
`public UsuarioAutenticado():Observable<any> return this.currentUserSubj.asObservable(); }`
 luego en el guard definir propiedad
 `token:string;`y dentro de canActivate( .........
 `this.autenticacionServicio.UsuarioAutenticado.subscribe(dato=>this.token=dato.accessToken)`
 `if (token){return true}this.route.navigate(['/portfolio']);return false}`
 y escucharlo tambien como un observable en el interceptor

Comment: @Legna Me devuelve una estructura similar a esta 
` { "jti": "51",   "iat": 1652204489,   "sub": "admin5",   "iss": "Main",   "exp": 1652244969}` Tendría que crear un modelos de datos con esta información verdad?

Comment: Primero tienes que decodificarlo en tu codigo, despues parsearlo a json, y por ultimo obtener los valores que necesitas. Puede que esto te sirva: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38552302/4326551

Comment: Logre resolverlo remplazando `if (currentUser && currentUser.accessToken)` por `if (currentUser)` No se si es correcto pero funciona. Note que el método `get usuarioAutenticado() { return this.currentUserSubject.value; }` No devuelve el par clave-valor sino solo el valor y en mi condicional intento compararlos lo que me devuelve el error.

Comment: @adriancasanova por favor, mueve la solución final a la respuesta en sí. No la pongas como comentario.